# jQuery: Stop scrolling text when margin-top < 0

Tags: jquery, if-statement, scroll, jquery-animate, margin

I got the scrolling text with 2 buttons working fine, but I can't seem to make it stop. I'm trying to disable the button if the margin < 0 with and if statement.

Please see the demo here:

http://jsbin.com/udumos/2/edit

Code:

```
$(function() {

    var margin = parseInt(jQuery('#content').css('margin-top'), 10);

    $('#scroll-down').click(function() {

        $('#content').animate({
            'margin-top': '+=50'
        }, 1000);

        return margin;

    });

    if (margin > 0) {
        $('#scroll-up').click(function() {

            $('#content').animate({
                'margin-top': '-=50'
            }, 1000);

        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update margin every click event.

```
$(function () {
    $('#scroll-down').click(function () {
        $('#content').animate({
            'margin-top': '+=50'
        }, 1000);
        return margin;
    });

    $('#scroll-up').click(function () {
        var margin = parseInt(jQuery('#content').css('margin-top'), 10);
        if (margin >= 0) {
            $('#content').animate({
                'margin-top': '-=50'
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move that if statement within the click. You also need to update margin everytime you click. I also then you want to put that if statement around the down click to make sure it cannot move down if you are at the top.

[updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/udumos/7/)

#### jQuery

```
$(function(){

   var margin = parseInt(jQuery('#content').css('margin-top'), 10);

   $('#scroll-down').click(function(){
       if( margin > 0 ) {
           // Update margin
           margin -= 50;
           $('#content').animate({
              'margin-top': '+=50'
           }, 1000);
       }
   });


   $('#scroll-up').click(function(){
       // Update margin
       margin += 50;
       $('#content').animate({
          'margin-top': '-=50'
       }, 1000);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much you two! HUGE help!